# Read lines from file and write directly to FIFO, without buffering in RAM

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file with very, very long lines.  A single line will not fit in memory.  I need to process each line separately, so I'd like to write each line to a FIFO node, sending EOF between lines.  This model works well for what I'm doing, and would be ideal.

The lines cannot be stored in RAM in their entirety, so the `read` built-in is not an option.  Whatever command I use needs to write directly--unbuffered--to the FIFO while reading from the multi-gigabyte source file.

How can I achieve this, preferably with pure bash and basic Linux utilities, and no special programs that I have to install?  I've tried things like `sed -u 'p'`, but unfortunately, I can't seem to get any common programs to send EOF between lines.

bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

### Update

I'd like to avoid utilities/tricks that read "line number X" from the file.  This file has thousands of very long lines; repeatedly evaluating the same line breaks would take far too long.  For this to complete in a reasonable timeframe, whatever program is reading lines will need to read each line in sequence, saving its previous position, much like `read` + pipe.

Comment: I think your goal is confused.  FIFOs have a limited capacity; your lines will be split.  It is not clear what you mean by 'EOF between lines'.  You indicate EOF by closing the FIFO for writing.  You may as well read the file in, for sake of argument, chunks of up to 16 KiB.  If there's a newline in it, write up to the newline and close the FIFO to send 'EOF'.  Then shuffle the data to move the residue to the start of the buffer and read more data into the end of the buffer, and iterate.  If there's no newline, simply send the 16 KiB of data. _[...continued...]_

Comment: By EOF, I mean close the stream.  It's just more intuitive to says "send EOF".

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ There's also the issue that you want to do something highly non-standard with standard tools.  That's going to be tricky.  The best bet from where I'm sitting is going to be Perl (or Python or other similar scripting language).  It will need to be something that can handle what C can handle to simulate what you require.  Exactly how long are your lines going to be?  More than 2 GiB?  Are you on a 64-bit machine?  How much main memory do you have?

Comment: The 'intuitiveness' of 'send EOF' vs 'close FIFO' is in the mind of the person doing the writing.  To anyone who's been programming any length of time, 'send EOF' is practically meaningless.

Comment: Indeed, I was about to suggest Python.  This is well beyond what you can accomplish with standard CLI tools.

Comment: I was under the impression that a FIFO node on a filesystem wasn't constrained by the value reported by `ulimit -p`.

Comment: FIFOs are basically file system representations of kernel buffers, usually with a fixed size.

Comment: Right, but are they hard-drive-backed?

Comment: At any given time, the (classic) FIFO has a finite limit on the amount of memory; POSIX only requires that to be 4 KiB, but it is often larger than that.  The information in the FIFO will be held in memory.  What's going to be reading the FIFO?  That's going to have to hold the stuff in memory too!

Comment: md5sum is going to be reading from the FIFO.  I need to hash lines.

Comment: You need to hash lines?  That's tractable.

Comment: Well, there's a bit more processing involved, but that's the "big step"

Comment: `md5sum` is only going to be reading from the FIFO until you first close it; it is only going to hash the first line.

Comment: Right, that's the idea.  It's like piping each line to md5sum, but hopefully file-system-backed.

Comment: Piping long lines through a FIFO is working fine when I do it manually.

Comment: FIFOs are RAM. If you do not have enough RAM to store an entire line in a bash variable, then the line will not fit into the FIFO either. Is your actual requirement to open the FIFO, write an entire line into it in multiple chunks and then close it? Because opening a FIFO for writing blocks until someone else opens it reading as well, and vice versa.

Comment: All I know is that writing a really long line to a FIFO and reading it at the same time works fine.  The line doesn't get cut off.

Comment: How are you going to wrap `md5sum` up so that for each line you get the MD5 hash of the line?  You're right that you can pipe data down a FIFO, but it will be sent in chunks, and read in chunks, and it won't matter in the slightest.  Your problem is the code to read an file with arbitrarily large lines, sending each to a FIFO that is opened, written to in a loop, and closed when the line is complete.

Comment: The problem is that I need to split a file into lines and send each line directly to a pipe, without storing it in a variable first.  If I can do that, my script will work.  My information about buffering might have been inaccurate, but the effective idea still applies.

Comment: Find a system call that works without copying the data.  IIRC, there's a weird one on Linux (completely non-standard) that does something like that, but I forget what the name is, and I forget what the constraints on it are.  I think you're on a hiding to nothing.  That system call isn't going to stop on lines.  You're going to have to read the lines piecemeal into memory.  This isn't going to matter, but you seem hung up on the issue of 'not in memory'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I should've been using a normal file, not a FIFO.  I was looking at this wrong.  `read` works the same way as `head`: it doesn't remember where it is in the file.  The stream remembers for it.  I don't know what I was thinking.  `head -n 1` will read one line from a stream, starting at whatever position the stream is already at.

```
#!/bin/bash

# So we don't leave a giant temporary file hanging around:
tmp=
trap '[ -n "$tmp" ] && rm -f "$tmp" &> /dev/null' EXIT
tmp="$(mktemp)" || exit $?

while head -n 1 > "$tmp" && [ -s "$tmp" ]; do
    # Run $tmp file through several programs, like md5sum
done < "$1"
```

This works quite effectively.  `head -n 1` reads each line in sequence from a basic file stream.  I don't have to worry about background tasks or blocking when reading from empty FIFOs, either.

Answer (score 3):

Let's think about the question "hashing lines that don't fit in memory", because that's a straightforward problem that you can solve with only a few lines of Python.

```
import sys
import hashlib

def hash_lines(hashname, file):
    hash = hashlib.new(hashname)
    while True:
        data = file.read(1024 * 1024)
        if not data:
            break
        while True:
            i = data.find('\n')
            if i >= 0:
                hash.update(data[:i]) # See note
                yield hash.hexdigest()
                data = data[i+1:]
                hash = hashlib.new(hashname)
            else:
                hash.update(data)
                break
    yield hash.hexdigest()

for h in hash_lines('md5', sys.stdin):
    print h
```

It's a bit wacky because most languages do not have good abstractions for objects that do not fit in memory (an exception is Haskell; this would probably be four lines of Haskell).

**Note:** Use `i+1` if you want to include the line break in the hash.

### Haskell version

The Haskell version is like a pipe (read right to left).  Haskell supports lazy IO, which means that it only reads the input as necessary, so the entire line doesn't need to be in memory at once.

A more modern version would use conduits instead of lazy IO.

```
module Main (main) where
import Crypto.Hash.MD5
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import Data.ByteString.Base16
import Prelude hiding (interact, lines, unlines)

main = interact $ unlines . map (fromStrict . encode . hashlazy) . lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashing long lines should be perfectly feasible, but probably not so easily in bash.

If I may suggest Python, it could be done like this:

```
# open FIFO somehow. If it is stdin (as a pipe), fine. Of not, simply open it.
# I suggest f is the opened FIFO.

def read_blockwise(f, blocksize):
    while True:
        data = f.read(blocksize)
        if not data: break
        yield data

hasher = some_object_which_does_the_hashing()
for block in read_blockwise(f, 65536):
    spl = block.split('\n', 1)
    hasher.update(spl[0])
    if len(spl) > 1:
        hasher.wrap_over() # or whatever you need to do if a new line comes along
        new_hasher.update(spl[1])
```

This is merely Python-orientated pseudo-code which shows the direction how to do what you seem to want to do.

Note that it will not be feasible without memory, but I don't think that it matters. The chunks are very small (and could be made even smaller) and are processed as they come along.

Encountering a line break leads to terminate processing of the old line and starting to process a new one.